# ImportError: No module named temboo.core.session

Tags: python, arduino, dropbox, arduino-yun, temboo

I'm using a python file to run on arduino yun.
but its giving me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/mnt/sda1/upload_picture.py", line 7, in module
>
> ```
> from temboo.core.session import TembooSession
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named temboo.core.session

**Code**

```
# coding=utf-8
# Script to upload files to Dropbox

# Import correct libraries
import base64
import sys
from temboo.core.session import TembooSession
from temboo.Library.Dropbox.FilesAndMetadata import UploadFile

print str(sys.argv[1])

# Encode image
with open(str(sys.argv[1]), "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

# Declare Temboo session and Choreo to upload files
session = TembooSession('yourSession', 'yourApp', 'yourKey')
uploadFileChoreo = UploadFile(session)

# Get an InputSet object for the choreo
uploadFileInputs = uploadFileChoreo.new_input_set()

# Set inputs
uploadFileInputs.set_AppSecret("yourAppSecret")
uploadFileInputs.set_AccessToken("yourAccessToken")
uploadFileInputs.set_FileName(str(sys.argv[1]))
uploadFileInputs.set_AccessTokenSecret("yourTokenSecret")
uploadFileInputs.set_AppKey("yourAppKey")
uploadFileInputs.set_FileContents(encoded_string)
uploadFileInputs.set_Root("sandbox")

# Execute choreo
uploadFileResults = uploadFileChoreo.execute_with_results(uploadFileInputs)
```

Comment: Well for starter .. do you have `temboo` module installed?

Answer (score 0):

The temboo SDK should be somewhere in the system path. To find out what are the different locations type this:

```
root@Arduino:/arduino# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 11 2014, 04:38:09) 
[GCC 4.6.3 20120201 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-      linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Once moving the SDK make sure whether there is a file "____init___.py" inside each proper folder (temboo, Library, core, so forth):

```
# ls -la /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/temboo/core/
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan 13 20:44 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root             0 Jan 13 20:44 ..
-rw----r--    1 root     root             1 Jan 13 20:44 __init__.py
-rw----r--    1 root     root         11253 Jan 13 20:44 choreography.py
-rw----r--    1 root     root          1932 Jan 13 20:44 exception.py
-rw----r--    1 root     root          4631 Jan 13 20:44 proxy.py
-rw----r--    1 root     root          2479 Jan 13 20:44 resource.py
-rw----r--    1 root     root          7034 Jan 13 20:44 session.py
-rw----r--    1 root     root          1009 Jan 13 20:44 util.py
```